# How to find the highest sum 3x3 grid in a randomly generated 4x4 grid (modulus grid, can wrap around)

Tags: java, arrays, grid, integration, mathematical-optimization

The way that I solved this is pretty inefficient.

**My solution:** I found, for every value in the 4x4 grid (2d array)the 3x3 grid for which the value is the center. I then summed this grid, added to an array, then once every 3x3 grid was found I found the largest sum in the new array.

According to my professor, this is a “fine solution for the size of grid we’re using”. But a more efficient solution exists for which he gave me the hint

**Hint at more efficient solution:** "One possibly useful hint: think of it as maximizing a two-dimensional integral, viewing the grid as a function of (row,column).”

To be clear, my solution gets full credit. I’m just completely lost on how to begin coding the more efficient solution.

Comment: An idea would be to first sum up all 2x2 grids, though I don't know whether that's the improvement your professor is referring to.

Comment: but aren’t there exceptions were the largest 2x2 grid may not lead to the largest 3x3 grid?

Comment: No, the sums would be used to calculate the 3x3 grids from. But it might not be a very useful improvement for 3x3s as it would be for 4x4s (which would simply be the sum of their 4 2x2s).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general solution for `NxM` grid in `O(N * M)` time and space.
Let's assume that the grid is has `NxM` size and we have to find `AxB` grid with the greatest sum`(1 <= A <= N, 1 <= B <= M)`. 
One can precompute an array `sum(x, y)` = sum of all elements with indices `1 <= i <= x` and `1 <= j <= y` (`sum(x, y) = sum(x - 1, y) + sum(x, y - 1) - sum(x - 1, y - 1) + a(x, y)`, where `a` is the initial grid).
Then the answer is `max(sum(x, y) - sum(x, y - B) - sum(x - A, y) + sum(x - A, y - B))` for all valid `x` and `y`. 
This solution doesn't consider the fact that the grid can wrap around but it can be easily fixed: Use a new grid `2Nx2M` which looks like:

```
aa
aa
```

The answer for this grid found by the algorithm described above is the answer for the initial problem with wrapping around.

Comment: This is a good solution, though unintelligible delivery. I finally decided to take the time to decipher what you might be trying to communicate, and yes, it is a very good solution, but it does not run in O(N*M) time. The initial calculation of the sum(x, y) array is O(N^2 * M^2). There are N*M calculations, each of which sums O(N*M) terms, on average. Part of me wants to +1 for the ingenuity. Part of me wants to -1 for the lack of clarity and wrong time assessment. So... I didn't vote... yet. +1 if you clarify and correct...

Comment: sum is computed in O(n*m). sum(x, y) = sum(x, y-1) + sum(x-1,y)-sum(x-1, y-1)+ a(x,y).  One formula. It is computed in constant time for fixed x and y.

Comment: I apologize. Yes. I forgot that by the time I finished deciphering the answer. Yes. This is truly a beautiful and elegant solution. I think it could be more readable if you clearly establish definitions of the components and describe why each step is taken. It is really hard to read right now. +1 anyway, for awesomeness.

Comment: Also, I think this is exactly the sort of thing the professor intended with his hint.